# Laptop Keyboard isn't detected by Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard, android-emulator

My Android Studio Emulator is not getting input from Laptop Keyboard. This was never happened before as i was working for more than 2 months. Now i can't give input from my laptop keyboard to emulator. i m using NEXUS 5X API 26 Emulator. Kindly let me know how to unlock laptop keyboard in android Emulator??.. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that under your emulator's preferences -> advanced settings, you have a check mark in "Enable keyboard input". I think some update to the tooling recently cleared this checkbox for some (all?) emulators.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open `AVD Manager` and click on Edit option on that particular emulator. Then click on `Enable Keyboard input` option. Now you are good to give input through laptop's keyboard

[image]

[image]